# Using typedef from inside a template as template argument type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to do something like this (completely synthetic example, because the real code is a bit to convoluted):

```
enum MyInfoType
{
    Value1, Value2
};

template<typename T> struct My_Type_Traits
{};

template<> struct My_Type_Traits<int>
{
    typedef MyInfoType InfoType;
};

template<typename T>
class Wrap
{
     template<My_Type_Traits<T>::InfoType INFO> int GetInfo()
     {...}
};

...
Wrap<int> w;
int info = w.GetInfo<Value1>();
```

So basically I'm trying to use a typedef from inside another struct as type of a template parameter. With this code however the compiler complains that `struct My_Type_Traits<T>::InfoType is not a type`. So what do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `typename` keyword: like `typename My_Type_Traits<T>::InfoType` to let the compiler know you're referring to a nested type.